What do they mean in the book of Daniel when they say God of fortresses?
A friend of mine has suggested he thinks the god of fortresses might be in relation to AI being the antichrist as it is a god never seen before. Does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Dan 11:38 - And in their place, he will honor a god of
fortresses—a god his fathers did not know—with gold, silver,
precious stones, and riches.


Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Short Answer: We don't know for sure.
Mars: It could refer to a deity associated with war, such as Mars, which was worshipped by the Phoenicians and Romans.
According to Cambridge Bible for Schools and Colleges

it is not certain who is meant by the ‘god of strongholds’: possibly
the reference is to some deity (? Mars) of whose worship by Antiochus
we have no other notice; more probably, however, the name is simply an
alternative designation of Jupiter Capitolinus.

Jupiter Olympus: This deity was not known among the Syrians until Antiochus introduced it.
The Benson Commentary says:

This seems to be either Jupiter Olympus, never introduced among the
Syrians till Antiochus did it, or, as others rather suppose, Mars, the
god of war, whom Antiochus ordered to be worshipped in his dominions:
which latter opinion seems the more likely, as Antiochus was almost
always engaged in some war or other, and appears to have depended most
upon his sword for raising himself to power and dignity.



1 ... The hypothesis that Daniel refers to the time of the Maccabean revolt, when Antiochus Epiphanes defiled the temple, makes good sense here.


In commenting on Dan 11:38, Barnes says:

The God of forces - Margin, Mauzzim, or gods protectors; or, munitions. Hebrew, מעזים mâ‛uzym; Latin Vulgate, Maozim; Greek,
Μαωξεὶμ Maōxeim; Syriac, "the strong God;" Luther, Mausim; Lengerke,
der Vesten - fastnesses, fortresses. The Hebrew word מעוז mâ‛ôz
means, properly, a strong or fortified place, a fortress; and Gesenius
(Lexicon) supposes that the reference here is to "the god of
fortresses, a deity of the Syrians obtruded upon the Jews, perhaps
Mars."

As any survey of the many commentaries on this passage will show, there is great diversity and speculation about this.  All that can be said is that the king who adopts the "god of fortresses" is "the king of the north" as V40 makes clear.
The modern phenomenon of AI cannot be said to be such a god of fortresses (although it is certainly "worshiped" as a deity by some.)
Barnes further comments:

It is, that the only god which he would acknowledge would be force, or
power, or dominion. He would set at nought the worship of the god of
his fathers, and all the usual obligations and restraints of religion;
he would discard and despise all the pleadings of humanity and
kindness, as if they were the weaknesses of women, and he would depend
solely on force. He would, as it were, adore only the "god of force,"
and carry his purposes, not by right, or by the claims of religion,
but by arms. ...
The general sentiment is, that all obligations of religion, and
justice, and compassion, would be disregarded, and he would carry his
purposes by mere power, with the idea, perhaps, included, as seems to
be implied in the remainder of the verse, that he would set up and
adore such a foreign god as would be a suitable representation of this
purpose. ...
Next to mammon, the god that is most adored in this world is the "god
of force"

Any survey of history will show that all false religion eventually unites with state power to enforce its false ideas with state power.

Sometimes, it helps to determine what is NOT the god of fortresses, which might be called a “figure-ground” approach to hermeneutics.

Let’s consider the literal Hebrew interlinear translation of Daniel 11:36-40.

And shall do according to his own will the king and he shall exalt and
magnify himself above every god and against the God of gods shall
speak blasphemies and shall prosper till has been accomplished the
wrath for what has been determined shall be done. And the God of his
fathers neither he shall regard nor the desire of women and any god
nor regard for above [them] all he shall exalt himself. But a god of
fortresses (mauzzim, SH 4581- a place or means of safety, protection,
strength) in their place he shall honor and a god which not did know
his fathers he shall honor with gold and silver and with stones
precious and pleasant things. Thus he shall act against the fortresses
strongest with a god foreign which he shall acknowledge [and] advance
[its] glory and he shall cause them to rule over many and the land
divide for gain.

https://biblehub.com/interlinear/daniel/11.htm
There are five categories of gods described here:
a.  The God of gods
b.  The God (or god) of his fathers
c.  The God (or god) associated with the “desire of women”
d.  A foreign god, a god of safety/strength/fortresses, who can act against the strongest fortresses
e.  All other gods
We can guess that the God of gods is a superlative expression for YHWH.
The God (or god) of his fathers is a reference to another monotheistic religion, perhaps Islam.
The “desire of women” speculatively might be a reference to the promise given to Eve, namely that her seed will bruise the serpent’s head, and thus be a reference to a daughter of Eve bearing Messiah/Christ.
We don’t know the identity of the foreign god of safety/strength/fortresses, but in context, it certainly excludes Judaism and Christianity.
The contemptible/vile person described donates massive wealth and gives honor to this foreign god, whatever it might be, relying on it for victory over fortresses.
Even if we don't know what this god is named, I believe that description is a good start, perhaps the best we can do for now.
